# predicting heavily skewed outcome

Tags: generalized-linear-model, predictive-models, prediction

the outcome variable of my data is heavily right skewed with some values being exact zeros and otherwise continuous. I modeled it by a zero-inflated compound poisson (Tweedie) distribution. I also tried a Gamma glm and a Gamma hurdle model, the outcome of both is about the same.

I am not very happy with the predictions, see here the observed/predicted plot:

[image]

and here the plot of observed against the absolute error:

[image]

prediction in the 2000-5000 area is the best, while it is very bad in the other regions, very high values and very small values are not tracked at all.

Is there a way to improve this?

Comment: Why not leverage quantile regression? It's robust to outliers or extreme values and, using Rob Hyndman's method described in this paper, you can fit all of the quantiles. Once you have the full predicted distribution, you can assign any probabilistic distribution that makes sense to you. http://robjhyndman.com/papers/smart-meter-quantiles.pdf

Answer (score 2):

From the plots, zero inflation does not seem to be the problem, so I am not surprised you don't like the results.

It appears that there is a nonlinear relationship between the DV and the IV.  One general solution to such problems is to use smoothers.  There are a wide range of these, but perhaps the most commonly used is restricted cubic splines.

Another possibility is to transform the dependent variable. Since there are 0's, taking logs isn't right (and adding some arbitrary constant is ... well, arbitrary) but one method is fractional polynomials.  I was just at the Southeast SAS Users Group and one presentation was by George Knafl who has written a lot about these.  Of course, he used SAS, but methods are available in R and (I presume) other packages.

Comment: Fractional polynomials are very well supported in Stata.

Comment: can somebody recommend an R package for this? I don't use SAS or Stata.